# I'm having problems transforming a mesh made of vertices into a polygon to use in UV editing

Tags: modeling, uv

I tried looking for a way to turn these vertices into a polygon but I didn't find anything

[image]

Comment: are you using the Skin modifier? In that case you need to apply it

Comment: It's also possible to use geometry nodes to UV unwrap dynamically.

Comment: @moonboots  yes i am using skin modifier

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady how ?

Comment: By using UV Unwrap node.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady 
I'm a beginner and I still don't know how to work with it and no yt video can provide me with what I need :/

Comment: First you should explain why you need it, what you want to achieve. Dynamic uv unwrapping is very hard unless you're willing to just unwrap each face separately.